# Two Amplifier problem 1

Tags: amplifier, differential

[image]

The two questions I am confused about are:

(a)Determine the value of REE to give emitter currents IE of 350 μA in each transistor and the smallest value of RC to enable a 1 volt peak-peak maximum output signal voltage

(b) Determine equations for Adm and Acm and calculate the theoretical values of differential-mode gain and common-mode gain for your designed circuit.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109279/discussion-on-question-by-s123l2000-two-amplifier-problem-1).

Answer (score 2):

<sub>\$\color{red}{\text{This answer formalizes comments under the question into a suitable format}}\$</sub>

### Part (a) - REE and RC

What is the current through REE required to be?

> *@Andyaka 2 times IE – Saahil2000*

what is the quiescent voltage at the emitters?

> *@Andyaka -0.7V? – Saahil2000*

Correct, so now use ohms law to calculate REE (6143 ohms): -

[image]

So, for either of the two transistors, what could be the maximum and what could be the minimum current that flows when a large signal is applied?

Hint - you know that the inputs to both transistors are opposite polarity and so you can assume the "common" (or shared) emitter voltage remains at -0.7 volts hence (as previously understood), total current in REE is 700 uA.

> *So the max is 700uA and the min is 0? How does this relate to finding
>   the maximum output voltage I am confused – Saahil2000*

You use Ohms law - what value of resistor produces a 1 volt p-p signal when the current is 700 uA p-p?

> Rc = 1.428 k ohms – Saahil2000

That's what I get!

### Part (b) - common mode gain

Given that both inputs are assumed to be rising up and down together (that's what common mode means), you can calculate the change in the common emitter voltage and use that change in voltage to imply a change in emitter current. That change in emitter current is shared equally between both transistors hence, half that change of current flows through Rc.

This means that the common-mode gain is \$\dfrac{R_C}{2\cdot R_{EE}}\$ = 0.116

### Part (b) - differential mode gain

Here we can ignore the shared emitter resistor REE (because the shared emitter voltage is constant) and focus on what is called the internal emitter resistor \$r_E\$. The voltage gain for a single common emitter amplifier with no emitter resistor is: -

$$\dfrac{R_C}{r_E}$$

But, because we are applying a differential signal the above voltage gain is halved because each base only receives 50% of the full differential signal hence the differential gain of a long-tailed pair (old-fashioned language) is: -

$$\dfrac{R_C}{2\cdot r_E}$$

Comment: +1 just for finding a decent way to handle this sort of all too common question. I'd like to +1 again for patience!

Comment: @Andy aka....what kind of input signal did you assume for the "differential mode"? The symmetric difference V1=-V2 ? In this case, the last expression would be NOT correct. For V1=-V2 the common emitter node would have a constant DC voltage (no feedback) and the simple common emiiter configuration must be considered.

Comment: @LvW I suspect you are making an important point (you usually do) but, I'm not getting what it is. Please spell it out a bit more.

Comment: For V1=-V2 there will be no change of current through REE. Hence, the emitter voltage remains uneffected - and the left transitor behaves like a common emiiter amplifier without any negative feedback. Hence: Gain=-gmRc=-Rc/re. However, in case of V2=0 we have some negative feedback caused by (primarily) hie=1/gm=re of the most right transistor. In this case, we have Gain=-0.5*Rc/re.

Comment: I did assume V1=-V2 because of the inputs being capacitively coupled. And, I assumed the input was balanced. Are you saying that to be thorough, I should consider the scenario when V2 = 0?

Comment: I am afraid, I have to add something important: We have forgotten to define the gain. Of course, it is important if we use - for the definition - the input signal at one of the inputs or the DIFFERENCE of both inputs. In the latter case the "total input" is V1-V2=-2V2 (for V1=-V2) and your result is the correct one. Only for gain=Vout/V1 (my assumption) we arrive at -Rc/re. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem @LvW

Comment: @S123l2000 if we are done with the Q and A now, can you formally accept the answer please? If there is something you don't understand (other than what your latest question asks), please leave a comment. [How to formally accept an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png).